# How do i import and eliminate first two row of website in msaccess while importing html pages

Tags: ms-access, import, vba

can we import a linked table from HTML document from VBA code?
if we can then can we delete the first row while importing?
[while importing html table can we delete the first row? for image. click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCzCq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import to temporary table all rows as text and then copy to working table only required rows by single query.

Comment: can you explain in detail? can i use query for that and how can i change datatype

Comment: When you finish the import to new table, you will receive a table with fields F1, F2, F3..., then you create a query, which takes the data from this table, select rows, where `IsNumeric([F1])=True`, most of data will be converted to destination data type automatically, probably you will need some conversion if numbers have different decimal separators or date fields are not standard. Also you will be able to validate if imported data file has correct columns, additional VBA code needed for this.